# Automatic text highlighting

Tags: text

Does anyone know of a piece of software or browser plugin that highlights a text to help reading it? Imagine a box that slowly moves across a text almost like in Karaoke. I need something similar but for webpages text or text files. Thank you for any suggestion.

Edit: something like this, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za8tMANFyXI

Answer (score 0):

OpenSpritz: a free speed reading bookmarklet.

https://gun.io/blog/openspritz-a-free-speed-reading-bookmarklet/

Jetzt:  Speed reader extension for chrome

https://github.com/ds300/jetzt

Readline: Simple Spritz inspired Chrome extension let's you speed read any selected text on a website word-by-word.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readline/hjbkmfadmomgaokjodomncmbgmmodona

Read It: Drag the link above into your hot bar. Click it to speed-read any selected text.

http://www.mikeprescott.net/ReadIt.html

Comment: Thank you Kyodake, I didn't know about this speed reading technique. I need something slightly different though... Thank you very much anyway!